# Auto resize row heights while sorting or filtering

Tags: nattable

I can not handle auto row heights resizing.
I tried to use [AutomaticRowHeightExample](https://www.javatips.net/api/nebula.widgets.nattable-master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/examples/_102_Configuration/AutomaticRowHeightExample.java), but without success.

Another inspiration was [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781957/) question, but also did not worked (see my code example). If I sort/filter, in console output I can see numbers of painted rows `i` while creating `PaintListener`, but row heights are not updated.

Creating table:

```
public class NatTableFactory {
  
  // another code

  private NatTable createTable(Composite parent, List<TableLine> tLines, String[][] propertyNames,
      PropertyToLabels[] propToLabels, TableParams params, TextMatcherEditor<TableLine>editor, boolean openableParts) {
    
    BodyLayerStack bodyLayerStack =
        new BodyLayerStack(
                tLines,
                tLines.get(0).getLength(),
                params.getColumnIndicesForRowHeaders());
    
    DataLayer bodyDataLayer = bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer();
    Integer[] rowHeights = getRowHeights(params);
    if( rowHeights != null && rowHeights.length > 0 ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < rowHeights.length; i++ ) {
        if( rowHeights[i] != null )
          bodyDataLayer.setRowHeightByPosition(i, (int) (rowHeights[i] * ApplicationSizeManager.getRowSizeCoefficient()));
      }
    }
    Integer[] colWidths = getColumnWidths(params);
    if( colWidths != null && colWidths.length > 0 ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < colWidths.length; i++ )
        if( colWidths[i] != null )
          bodyDataLayer.setColumnWidthByPosition(i, colWidths[i]);
    }

    DataLayer columnHeaderDataLayer = null;
    if( propertyNames != null ) {
      IDataProvider columnHeaderDataProvider = 
          new DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider(propertyNames[0], propToLabels[0].getPropertyToLabels());
      columnHeaderDataLayer =
          new DefaultColumnHeaderDataLayer(columnHeaderDataProvider);
    }

    //copy command: include table headers
    bodyLayerStack.registerCommandHandler(new CustomCopyDataCommandHandler(bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer(), columnHeaderDataLayer, null, params.getColumnHeaderGroups()));

    CompositeLayer composite = null;
    if( propertyNames != null ) {
      ColumnHeaderLayer columnHeaderLayer =
          new ColumnHeaderLayer(
              columnHeaderDataLayer,
              bodyLayerStack,
              (SelectionLayer)null);
      columnHeaderLayer.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getColumnHeaderLayerConfiguration(false));

      SortHeaderLayer<TableLine> sortHeaderLayer =
          new SortHeaderLayer<TableLine>(
              columnHeaderLayer,
              new GlazedListsSortModel<TableLine>(
                  bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(),
                  getSortingColumnPropAccessor(propertyNames[0]),
                  configRegistry,
                  columnHeaderDataLayer));

      Integer[] hrHeights = params.getHeaderRowHeights();
      if( hrHeights != null && hrHeights.length > 0 )
        columnHeaderDataLayer.setRowHeightByPosition(0, (int) (hrHeights[0] * ApplicationSizeManager.getRowSizeCoefficient()));
      
      composite = new CompositeLayer(1, 2);
      composite.setChildLayer(GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, sortHeaderLayer, 0, 0);
      composite.setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, bodyLayerStack, 0, 1);
    } else {
      composite = new CompositeLayer(1, 1);
      composite.setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, bodyLayerStack, 0, 0);
    }
    
    composite.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getCompoositeLayerConfiguration());
    
    NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent, composite, false);
    
    if( params.getAutoFitColWidthIndices().size() > 0 )
      registerAutoResizeColCmdHandler(natTable, composite, bodyLayerStack, params.getAutoFitColWidthIndices());
    
    // register AutoResizeRowCommandHandler
    // something wrong here?
    
    registerAutoResizeRowCommandHandler(natTable, composite, bodyLayerStack, params.getAutoFitColWidthIndices());
    
    setNatTableContentTooltip(natTable);
    
    natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
   
    natTable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
    
    if(columnHeaderDataLayer!=null)
      natTable.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getCustomComparatorConfiguration(columnHeaderDataLayer));
    
    natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());

    setNatTableContextMenu(natTable, openableParts);
    
    natTable.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getNatTableConfiguration());
    
    //
    /*
    natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration()
    {
      {
        cellPainter = new LineBorderDecorator(new AutomaticRowHeightTextPainter(5));
      }
    });*/
   
    natTable.configure();

    editor.setFilterator(new TextFilterator<TableLine>() {

      @Override
      public void getFilterStrings(List<String> baseList, TableLine element) {
        for( int i = 0; i < element.getLength(); i++ )
          baseList.add("" + element.getObjectByColumnForFilter(i));
      }
    });
    editor.setMode(TextMatcherEditor.REGULAR_EXPRESSION);
    bodyLayerStack.getFilterList().setMatcherEditor(editor);

    NatTableContentProvider.addNatTableData(natTable, bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer(), bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataProvider());
    
    return natTable;
  }
  
  // another code
}
```

register AutoResizeRowCommandHandler:

```
// in class NatTableFactory
private void registerAutoResizeRowCommandHandler(NatTable natTable, ILayer commandLayer, ILayer positionLayer, List<Integer> colPositions)
{
  natTable.registerCommandHandler(new AutoResizeRowCommandHandler(commandLayer, positionLayer));
  PaintListener listener = new PaintListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
    {
      System.out.println("paintControl");
      for (int i = 0; i < natTable.getRowCount(); i++)
      {
        System.out.println(i);
        InitializeAutoResizeRowsCommand rowCommand = new InitializeAutoResizeRowsCommand(natTable, i, natTable.getConfigRegistry(), new GCFactory(
              natTable));
        AutoResizeRowsCommand command = new AutoResizeRowsCommand(rowCommand);
        natTable.doCommand(command);
      }
    }
  };
  natTable.addPaintListener(listener);
}
```

BodyLayerStack:

```
public BodyLayerStack(List<TableLine> values, int columnCount, Integer[] columnIndicesForRowHeaders)
  {
    EventList<TableLine> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);
    TransformedList<TableLine, TableLine> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);

    // this.filterList = new FilterList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList); //changed to:
    // use the SortedList constructor with 'null' for the Comparator
    // because the Comparator will be set by configuration
    sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, null);
    // wrap the SortedList with the FilterList
    filterList = new FilterList<>(sortedList);
    
    bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<TableLine>(filterList, getColumnAccessor(columnCount));
    bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);

    IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
      
      @Override
      public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
        int columnIndex = bodyDataLayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(columnPosition);
        int rowIndex = bodyDataLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);

        if(isRowHeader(columnIndicesForRowHeaders, columnIndex)) 
          configLabels.addLabel(NatTableFactory.RowHeaderLabel);
        else
        {
          // get dataTypes at actual positions and add/refresh labels
          String label = filterList.get(rowIndex).getObjectTypeByColumn(columnIndex);
          // adjust label according to autoFitWitdh option
          if(filterList.get(rowIndex).isAutoFitColWidth(columnIndex))
            label += "_" + NatTableFactory.AutoFitWidthLabel;
          else
            label += "_" + NatTableFactory.NoAutoFitWidthLabel; 
          configLabels.addLabel(label);
        }
      }
    };
    bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);

    GlazedListsEventLayer<TableLine> glazedListsEventLayer = new GlazedListsEventLayer<>(bodyDataLayer, filterList);
    
    selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(glazedListsEventLayer, false);
    selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(getSelectionModel());
    selectionLayer.addConfiguration(getSelectionConfiguration());
    //
    viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);
    setUnderlyingLayer(new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer));

  }
```

If I call `natTable.doCommand(rowCommand)` instead of `natTable.doCommand(command)` while registering handler, row heights are updated correctly, but table is painted repetitively, scroll bar blinks all the time.

I tried also:

```
private void registerAutoResizeRowCommandHandler(NatTable natTable, ILayer commandLayer, ILayer positionLayer, List<Integer> colPositions)
  {
    natTable.registerCommandHandler(new AutoResizeRowCommandHandler(commandLayer, positionLayer));
    BodyLayerStack bodyLayerStack = (BodyLayerStack) positionLayer;
    natTable.addPaintListener(
        new AutoResizeRowPaintListener(
            natTable, 
            bodyLayerStack.getViewportLayer(), 
            bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer()));
  }
```

Any idea what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it:

in `NatTableFactory`:

```
private NatTable createTable(Composite parent, List<TableLine> tLines, String[][] propertyNames,
  PropertyToLabels[] propToLabels, TableParams params, TextMatcherEditor<TableLine>editor, 
  boolean openableParts) 
{
  // another code
  registerAutoResizeRowCommandHandler(natTable, composite, bodyLayerStack);
  //another code
  return natTable;
}
```

and:

```
private void registerAutoResizeRowCommandHandler(NatTable natTable, 
  CompositeLayer commandLayer, BodyLayerStack bodyLayerStack)
{
  natTable.registerCommandHandler(new AutoResizeRowCommandHandler(commandLayer, bodyLayerStack));

  natTable.addPaintListener(
    new AutoResizeRowPaintListener(
        natTable, 
        bodyLayerStack.getViewportLayer(), 
        bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer()));

}
```

My mistake was in `BodyLayerStack`:

```
viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);
setUnderlyingLayer(new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer));
```

correct is:

```
viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);
setUnderlyingLayer(viewportLayer);
```

Thanks [Dirk Fauth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2955861/dirk-fauth)!

Answer (score 0):

Well for a complete answer I would need quite some time to explain the internals of NatTable. Not sure if you are really interested in this. So I simply answer how to do it right.

With NatTable 1.6 the `AutoResizeRowPaintListener` was added to simplify the auto row resize task. Information about this can be found here: https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_160.php

Comment: Hi [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2955861/dirk-fauth), thank you for your answer! I tried your solution and updated question, it won't work. Only thing that updates row heights according to content is `natTable.doCommand(new AutoResizeRowsCommand(natTable, i)),` but this probably should not listen to `PaintListener`, it is performed endlessly - every time something is painted, command is called again.

Comment: Have you removed the other solution when testing my proposal? There should be no endless resizing, despite you have a configuration that tries an auto row resize with shrinking with multiple columns. Maybe your style configuration has something for the painters that causes the effect. But since that information is hidden as you are having your code in some static hell, there is not much I can say.

Comment: Hello [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2955861/dirk-fauth), I removed my solution while trying yours. I did try `natTable.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {...})` as well, but with the same result: it runs endlessly. I updated table configuration and BodyLayerStack in my question. I will investigate more. Thanks anyway for trying to help!!

Comment: I use also `AutoResizeColumnCommandHandler`, which works fine.